# Why were Law Lords created peers of different ranks?

Tags: england, law

I  cross-referenced the men below with [List of law life peerages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_law_life_peerages) to check that these Law Lords were created life peers, and didn't inherit peerage. Most Law Lords are created as Barons, but note the different ranks on  [Lord High Chancellors and Lord Keepers of Great Britain (1707–present)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lord_Chancellors_and_Lord_Keepers#Lord_High_Chancellors_and_Lord_Keepers_of_Great_Britain_(1707%E2%80%93present)).

I'm aware of [changes in 2007 to the Lord Chancellor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Chancellor)

> Formerly, the Lord Chancellor was also the presiding officer of the [House of Lords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Lords), the head of the judiciary in England and Wales and the presiding judge of the [Chancery Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Court_of_Justice#Chancery_Division) of the [High Court of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Court_of_Justice), but the [Constitutional Reform Act 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_Reform_Act_2005) transferred these roles to the [Lord Speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Speaker), the [Lord Chief Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Chief_Justice_of_England_and_Wales) and the [Chancellor of the High Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_of_the_High_Court) respectively. T

Most [Lords of Appeal in Ordinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lords_of_Appeal_in_Ordinary) (1876-2009) are barons save:

- Viscount Sumner (serving 1919-130).
- Viscount Radcliffe (1949-1964)

[Lord Chief Justice of England and Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Chief_Justice_of_England_and_Wales)

- Earl Hadwicke (1733-1737)
- Charles Pratt, Earl Camden (1762-1766)
- Sir Alexander Cockburn, Bt (1859-1875) wasn't created a Peer! Why not? Did he flub judging?
- Viscount Alverstone (1900-1913)
- Marquess of Reading (1913-1921). Wow! What did he do to be promoted to Marquess? Did he judge that masterfully?

Comment: In the case of The Marquess of Reading, his elevation in the peerage is explained in this Wikipedia page. He was made baron when he became Lord Chief Justice, and the subsequent elevations to viscount and earl were for his service during WW1 and finally to Marquess as a reward for serving as Viceroy of India.

Comment: According to [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Alexander_Cockburn,_12th_Baronet#Life), When Sir Alexander Cockburn finally relented in 1864 to receive a peerage (having declined several previous times, probably to remain eligible to sit in  the House of Commons), Queen Victoria refused:  "*this peerage has been more than once previously refused upon the ground of the notoriously bad moral character of the Chief Justice*".

Comment: Many of the examples are historical. Current practice is to grant **Life Peerages** only, at the rank of Baron/Baroness.